# form1 string is don't pass to form2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

want to make form1 `pubId` value changed from form2. `pubId` is always get null didn't change. How can I solve this problem?

Form1 code:

```
public string pubId = string.Empty;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        form2 _frm2 = new form2();
        _frm2 .FormClosed += _frm2_FormClosed;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.show(ex);
    }
}

private void _frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (pubId == "8")
    {
       MessageBox.show("works");
    }
}
```

Form2 code:

```
public void buttonsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    idfrm2 = "8";

    form1 _frm1 = new form1 ();                                          
    _frm1.pubId = _idfrm2;

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: What framework do you use? If non why do you expect it to work?

Comment: in form2 : `_frm1.pubId = "Your string goes there";`

Comment: @Martijn Woudstra  I am using Framework v3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain reference to Form2 inside a List of controls maintained by Form1 and access it as below :

Form1 Code :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 localfrm2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.FormClosed += Frm2_FormClosed;

        localfrm2 = frm2;
            frm2.Show();

    }

    private void Frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(localfrm2.PubId);
    }
}

Form 2 :

  public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string PubId { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PubId = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Upvote if this solves your problem

Comment: 'PubId' is not changed next click

Comment: same as you. but  'PubId = "8";' is changed by cell value. I meant 'string PubId' is dynamic. Problem is 'PubId' is not changed next click

 'private void Frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((Form2)this.CustomControls[0]).PubId);
        }'

Comment: Checkout my updated code. This time i have even used a textbox on form2 and accessed the updated value on form1. This works even on 2nd click+. Try and let me know . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this line you create a new form with new empty pubId.

```
form1 _frm1 = new form1 ();
```

Just create a constructor for form2 to pass it.
For example:

```
private string _pubId;
public form2(string pubId)
{
    _pubId = pubId;
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
form2 _frm2 = new form2(pubId);
```

Comment: Which form for create constructor?

Comment: I have this error message 'Error 3 'form' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments'

Comment: Just get two constructors. One with parameter and another with string parameter